# Где проводить валидацию наличия сущности по ID в Nest.js?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, typescript, валидация, nestjs

Валидация типов входящих данных обычно реализуется через [`ValidationPipe()`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#auto-validation) с помощью `class-validator`.

```typescript
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}
```

Но валидация существования сущности с заданным ID требует дополнительной логики.

Как и где её реализовать?